# How can I scrape an interactive map using python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, tooltip

I have been trying to scrape a leaflet concert map(see picture below), where the information only shows if you hover over the seat with your mouse. I have searched the internet up and down, I slowly start to understand where the information comes from by going into the Network Tab, but I still cannot fully grasp it.

[image: map]

This is [the link to the page](https://www.ticketcorner.ch/event/disney-in-concert-dreams-become-true-hallenstadion-13050005/#seatmap-tab)

Where is this information saved and how can I access it? I would everything that shows up when you hover over the map and see in the small box or on the side when you select it (everything that is found in `class="tickettype-item"`)
I tried something like this, but I'm sure it's nowhere near enough. I would greatly appreciate the help as I'm really keen on understanding what's happening here and how I can solve this.

```
list_of = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="seatmap-tab"]/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/canvas')
for item in list_of:
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(item)
    try:
        description = wait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="seatmap-tab"]/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div'))).text
        print(description)
        action.perform()
    except:
        action.perform()
```

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

Comment: In `Network Tab` you could clear all requests, select `Fetch/XHR` to see what JavaScript loads - and next you should click `Sallplan` on page - and then you can see it loads JSON data from https://api.eventim.com/seatmap/api/SeatMapHandler?smcVersion=v6.1&version=v6.2.11&cType=web&cId=8&evId=13050005&a_holds=1&a_rowRules=1&a_systemId=1&a_promotionId=0&a_sessionId=TCS_NO_SESSION&timestamp=27537247&expiryTime=27537257&chash=jhFtWmzezU&signature=TnNcSmSK7T9XhUkKvZ10QPl4cYXNwJSWqG-TLShmPoA&fun=json&areaId=0 but it is hard to understand this data.

Comment: information are NOT saved - JavaScript keeps it in memory and probably you may get from JavaScript something similar like in link in previous comment - so it may be simpler to read directly from link. And it may generate window with information only when you hover item on map (and move previous values) so you can't get all from HTML.